# basic: adding a profile in Volatility

Tags: forensics, macos

Just starting out with the Volatility framework.  I want to use a pre-built profile for OSX.
I've downloaded the MacProfileAll.zip file and have copied the profile I want into the `/Volatility/volatility/plugins/overlays/mac/` folder.

How do I get Volatility to know about this though?
When I use the command-line switch `--profile=MountainLion_10.8.2.AMD`, that doesn't work.
Doing a `python vol.py --info | grep Mac` only shows command-line switches, but no profiles.

It says in the instructions to just put the file in the "mac" folder.  Did I just completely miss a critical step?

Comment: This is a question for Volatility support forums.

Comment: I know and actually I'd be open to any suggestions.  There aren't any on the Volatility main site.  There is an IRC channel, but no luck there thus far.

Comment: NVM, I finally figured it out.  The profile need to go here:  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/volatility-2.3.1-py2.6.egg/volatility/plugins/overlays/mac at least on my system.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it.You can post this as an answer to your own question;self-answers are OK, it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
python vol.py --info|grep Profile
```

you should get the result like this below

```
$ vol.py --info |grep Profile
Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.6
Profiles
LinuxCentOS68x64      - A Profile for Linux CentOS68 x64
VistaSP0x64           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP0 x64
VistaSP0x86           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP0 x86
VistaSP1x64           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP1 x64
VistaSP1x86           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP1 x86
VistaSP2x64           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP2 x64
VistaSP2x86           - A Profile for Windows Vista SP2 x86
Win10x64              - A Profile for Windows 10 x64
Win10x64_10586        - A Profile for Windows 10 x64 (10.0.10586.306 / 2016-04-23)
Win10x64_14393        - A Profile for Windows 10 x64 (10.0.14393.0 / 2016-07-16)
Win10x86              - A Profile for Windows 10 x86
Win10x86_10586        - A Profile for Windows 10 x86 (10.0.10586.420 / 2016-05-28)
Win10x86_14393        - A Profile for Windows 10 x86 (10.0.14393.0 / 2016-07-16)
Win2003SP0x86         - A Profile for Windows 2003 SP0 x86
Win2003SP1x64         - A Profile for Windows 2003 SP1 x64
Win2003SP1x86         - A Profile for Windows 2003 SP1 x86
Win2003SP2x64         - A Profile for Windows 2003 SP2 x64
Win2003SP2x86         - A Profile for Windows 2003 SP2 x86
Win2008R2SP0x64       - A Profile for Windows 2008 R2 SP0 x64
Win2008R2SP1x64       - A Profile for Windows 2008 R2 SP1 x64
Win2008R2SP1x64_23418 - A Profile for Windows 2008 R2 SP1 x64 (6.1.7601.23418 / 2016-04-09)
Win2008SP1x64         - A Profile for Windows 2008 SP1 x64
Win2008SP1x86         - A Profile for Windows 2008 SP1 x86
Win2008SP2x64         - A Profile for Windows 2008 SP2 x64
Win2008SP2x86         - A Profile for Windows 2008 SP2 x86
Win2012R2x64          - A Profile for Windows Server 2012 R2 x64
Win2012R2x64_18340    - A Profile for Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (6.3.9600.18340 / 2016-05-13)
Win2012x64            - A Profile for Windows Server 2012 x64
Win2016x64_14393      - A Profile for Windows Server 2016 x64 (10.0.14393.0 / 2016-07-16)
Win7SP0x64            - A Profile for Windows 7 SP0 x64
Win7SP0x86            - A Profile for Windows 7 SP0 x86
Win7SP1x64            - A Profile for Windows 7 SP1 x64
Win7SP1x64_23418      - A Profile for Windows 7 SP1 x64 (6.1.7601.23418 / 2016-04-09)
Win7SP1x86            - A Profile for Windows 7 SP1 x86
Win7SP1x86_23418      - A Profile for Windows 7 SP1 x86 (6.1.7601.23418 / 2016-04-09)
Win81U1x64            - A Profile for Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64
Win81U1x86            - A Profile for Windows 8.1 Update 1 x86
Win8SP0x64            - A Profile for Windows 8 x64
Win8SP0x86            - A Profile for Windows 8 x86
Win8SP1x64            - A Profile for Windows 8.1 x64
Win8SP1x64_18340      - A Profile for Windows 8.1 x64 (6.3.9600.18340 / 2016-05-13)
Win8SP1x86            - A Profile for Windows 8.1 x86
WinXPSP1x64           - A Profile for Windows XP SP1 x64
WinXPSP2x64           - A Profile for Windows XP SP2 x64
WinXPSP2x86           - A Profile for Windows XP SP2 x86
WinXPSP3x86           - A Profile for Windows XP SP3 x86
```

If you are installing using homebrew, the path will be

```
/usr/local/Cellar/volatility/2.6/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/volatility/plugins/overlays/{{OS}}
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I finally figured it out. The profile need to go here: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/volatility-2.3.1-py2.6.egg/volatility/plu‌​gins/overlays/mac at least on my system.